# Spring MVC - Controlling which Entity fields are serialized

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, entity, dto

I am currently using my Entities directly as response types and request parameters on my controller methods (as opposed to DTOs). I wish filter out some fields from responses, is it better practice to annotate those fields **inside my Entity** class with @JsonIgnore (thus cluttering my model) or create a DTO specifically for the required fields. Which approach is considered better from a design perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create DTO. Reason for that is very simple, if you return entity you can pull out a lot of data from database(depending on you JPA annotation - @Lazy, @Eager annotation) and if you return DTO, you can always return only data you need.

@JsonIgnore annotation will always exclude property from serialization, but sometimes you want that property(for some specific request) and then you are in problem. This is simple situation where DTO can help you, because you can create it as you want, which fields you want.